# Allow access to website (API) only from certain domain in IIS

Tags: iis, web-config

Given two websites:

- `a.com` is a public website and can be accessed by anyone.
- `b.com` is an API and can be accessed only from `a.com` domain.

How to restrict direct access to `b.com` in IIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IIS you have feature called IP Address and domain restrictions. You can use same for what you want to achieve. There you can specify either specific IP or domain to allow/deny access.